# Returning data from wikipedia using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Is there a service or api that allows wikipedia data regarding a string be retrieved only with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here: [API's for bots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#APIs_for_bots).

This is however not programming related. In the future, just consult their own API docs.

Answer (score 5):

There is a Wikipedia API (more precisely, MediaWiki, the engine of Wikipedia, has an API).
You can read more about it here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Here are some examples using jQuery:

get the formatted content of a page :

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", {page:"Red Sea clownfish", prop:"text"}, function(data) {console.log(data);});
```

get the source of a page :

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&callback=?", {titles:"Red Sea clownfish", prop: "revisions", rvprop:"content"}, function(data) {console.log(data);});
```

get the image names of a page:

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&callback=?", {titles:"Red Sea clownfish", prop: "images"}, function(data) {console.log(data);});
```

note the `&callback=?` that is needed for everything to work well (for the result to be JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that under normal circumstances, the wikipedia APIs or just regular "Screen Scraping" must be done server side and not directly from the browser. This is due to same-domain restrictions designed to prevent cross domain scripting attacks.